# Tomcat 8 unable to download excel or image

Tags: java, tomcat, mime-types, binaryfiles, tomcat8.5

Recently I have migrated one of my apps from Tomcat 7 (in Ubuntu 12.04.2) to 8.5 in Ubuntu 20.04.3 .

In Tomcat 8.5, it is failing to download a binary file like excel/image by clicking the download button on the webpage which is linked to a url like http://xx.yy.zz.pp:8080/testsite/bin/test.xls . It does not give any message. If this url is tried from the browser it shows only junk (binary) characters. Testing the url with "curl -s -I" shows content-type as text/html - though conf/web.xml under tomcat folder has proper mime-type mapping application/vnd.ms-excel against xls.

This works in Tomcat 7 without any issue.

It can show a normal text file using a similar url without any issue.

From Ubuntu command prompt checking  "file --mime-type test.xls" shows application/vnd.ms-excel . But tomcat is failing to identify that .

Comment: An Excel file is composed of _"junk characters"_ (binary data). Use `curl -i` to check what is the `Content-Type` of the downloaded file.

Comment: File is known . It is generated by one of our program which user can download by clicking a button.That button uses the type of link specified . Readable files under app folder could always be viewed from browser using complete url . That is failing in tomcat 8.5

Comment: Browsers use the `Content-Type` header of the server response to decide what to do with a file (e.g. they display `text/plain` files). Therefore you should check what MIME type is returned by your server. [`curl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html) with a `-I` switch allows you to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is returning Content-type as text/html in tomcat 8 . I checked its web.xml under conf folder but that is configured as application/vnd.ms-excel . In tomcat 7 it is returning that . Also in tomcat 8 it is showing server as nginx.

Comment: Please include NGINX configuration to your question.

Comment: NGINX was coming due to proxy server . Using the the url directly does not show any server. From linux command line I have tested the mime-type , it shows proper one . I have edited the question .